# Email is sending but no data is populating

Tags: php, html, email

My syntactical knowledge of is sadly not what it should be and im pretty sure im making very dumb mistake.

I have a HTML form and php file, both living on my server.
On sending, I receive an email, but the values in the html form are not populated.
Can anyone spot where I am going wrong.

HTML is:

```
 <form action="contact.php" mothod="post" id="contact-form" target="blank">
        <input class="form-control input-outline" id="formName" type="text" name="formName" placeholder="Full name:">
        <input class="form-control input-outline" id="formEmail" type="text" name="formEmail" placeholder="Email address:">
        <textarea class="form-control input-outline" id="formMessage" rows="6" cols="50" name="formMessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

PHP is:

```
<?php
    $email_to = "myemail@myaddress.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "New form submissions";

    $name = $_POST['formName']; // required
    $email = $_POST['formEmail']; // required
    $message = $_POST['formMessage']; // required

    $headers .= "\r\n Name: " . $name;
    $headers .= "\r\n Email: " . $email;
    $headers .= "\r\n Message: " . $message;

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $headers);
?>
```

If possible to explain my mistake so I can learn from it that would be amazing.

P.s.

Been at my desk for a very long time now coding away so if this is a very dumb mistake then thank you for your patience with me.

All the best -
W

Comment: What do you mean by "the values in the html form are not populated"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you did not define `$header`, so define it as an empty string. Then, if you meant to send an actual email header, then you must include a "from" header, as per the [specification](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> When sending mail, the mail must contain a `From` header. This can be set with the **additional_headers** parameter, or a default can be set in `php.ini`.

You've also made a typo in your HTML: `mothod -> method`.

```
$email_to = "myemail@myaddress.co.uk";
$email_subject = "New form submissions";

$name = $_POST['formName']; // required
$email = $_POST['formEmail']; // required
$message = $_POST['formMessage']; // required
$headers = "";

$headers .= "\r\n Name: " . $name;
$headers .= "\r\n Email: " . $email;
$headers .= "\r\n Message: " . $message;

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $headers);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for spotting my silly mistakes - PHP is not my strongest subject (as the above is showing - well that and 9 hours at my desk)

Answer (score 1):

probably your error is that in the form you have mothod instead of method

```
 <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" target="blank">
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - kinda embarrassing but this is how we learn

Comment: don't worry, they are things that happen